# Как передать данные в вложеный подзапрос?

Tags: sql-server

Есть куча параметров заказа, можно ли их присоиденить в "один" проход?

```
select * from [order]  cross join  ( select 
    max(case when id_par=1 then value end) p1,
    max(case when id_par=2 then value end) p2
    --  ....
    from orderparams where 
orderparams.id_order = [order].id  ) t
```

Тут ошибка в последней строчке, т.к. нельзя "вовнутрь"  запроса передать [order].id, оно там не доступно. Можно ли как-то связать эти таблицы таким образом не используя функцию или групировку? (mssql-server 2005) Параметров порядка 10-20 штук.

Comment: Сделайте `gorup by id_order` в подзапросе, добавьте это поле в список select и выполните обычный `ON t.id_order=[order].id`. Или посмотрите в сторону cross apply, сам не работал с ним, но что то подсказывает, что это то что вам надо

Comment: Да, здесь вместо `cross join` подойдёт `cross apply`.

Comment: А, apply доступен только с 2008 сервера ... а выборка не предполагает, что можно как то заранее ограничить количество записей ? Там же все равно происходит неявная группировка на каждом отдельном подзапросе, ради выполнения max. И может можно обойтись без подзапроса, а склеить таблицы напрямую. Ведь в order наверняка только одна запись на группу из params.

Comment: У меня 2005 v 9.0 apply работает.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Способ 1 - вытащите `id_order` наружу, тогда вам не понадобится `[order].id` внутри:

```
select * 
from [order] 
inner join (...) t on [order].id = t.id_order
```

Способ 2 - использование `cross apply`:

```
select *
from [order]
cross apply (
  select ...
  where id_order = [order].id
) t
```

Comment: С 10-ю **left join** 10 штук параметров 23 сек, c [1] **group** 7 секунд (удивлён)  с [2] **cross apply**  16 секунд.  Таблица params 900000 записей, order 500000 записей (база рабочая *онлайн*).